# Rust trait object with generic type parameter

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I have a trait `Transformable` which looks something like this:

```rust
pub trait Transformable {
    fn position(&self) -> Vec2f;
    fn set_position<V>(&mut self, position: V) where V: Into<Vec2f>;
}
```

And I have a `SceneNode` trait which I need to be a trait object, which looks something like this (although the details here are not really relevant):

```rust
pub trait SceneNode {
    fn update(&mut self, dt: Duration);
```

I'd like to enforce that `SceneNode` trait objects also implement the `Transformable` trait. However, the generic `V` in `Transformable` means that `SceneNode` cannot be a trait object.

I like having `V: Into<Vec2f>` as a generic type parameter on `Transformable` because it makes for a more convenient API instead of having to explicitly create new `Vec2f`'s all the time, e.g.:

```rust
impl From<[f32; 2]> for Vec2f { ... }
transformable.set_position([10.0, 10.0]); // Yes please.
transformable.set_position([10.0, 10.0].into()); // No thanks.
transformable.set_position(Vec2f::new(10.0, 10.0)); // No thanks.
```

Is there a way for `SceneNode` to implement `Transformable` that allows me to keep this type parameter or in which `Transformable` can be redesigned such that I can still have the current usage?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there's very little wiggle room here. If you need the trait to be object safe, i.e. be able to be turned into a trait object, none of its methods can have generic type parameters. Period. The only thing I can think of is splitting the generic `set_position` into its own trait with a blanket impl:

```
pub trait Transformable {
    fn position(&self) -> Vec2f;
    // no longer generic + a different name for trait method resolution
    fn set_position_raw(&mut self, position: Vec2f);
}

// put the generic version into a new trait...
pub trait SetPosition {
    fn set_position<V>(&mut self, position: V) where V: Into<Vec2f>;
}

// ...with a blanket impl for `Transformable` types
impl<T: ?Sized> SetPosition for T where T: Transformable {
    fn set_position<V>(&mut self, position: V) where V: Into<Vec2f> {
        self.set_position_raw(position.into());
    }
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
let mut t = SomeTransformableType { ... };
t.set_position([1.0, 1.0]);
let t_dyn: &mut dyn Transformable = &mut t;
t.set_position([-1.0, -1.0]);
```